# is there a way to retreive cookie automatically in curl

Tags: api, session, curl, cookies, token

I made a script which aims to automate the tests on a platform via curls on the APIs used, however on one of the APIs I have to retrieve the cookie from the dev tools (capture below) every day to put it on the curl request otherwise it doesn't work.

[dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ01b.png)

I still tried to retrieve the cookie with a curl but I still have the cookie field which is empty

[curl without cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY3Yl.png)

by inserting the cookie myself, it works well but as I said, I have to do it daily and it breaks all the automatic aspect of my work

[works by inserting curl manualy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDDT5.png)

I need you to know if there is a possibility to retrieve this cookie automatically without having to change my request every day

thanks